# Jquery with variable selector doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, selector

I don't know why the selector jquery doesn't accept a variable.

```
function myfunction()
{
    $.ajax({
           url: "/file.php", dataType: "json", type: "GET",
           success: function(data)
           {
              var data = data.split("-");
              data.forEach(function(entry) 
              {
                 if (entry != "")
                 {
                     $("#check_status_" + entry).html('text');
                 }
              });
           }
    });
}
```

variable entry is not empty, the problem is when I put it into the selector.
Thanks.

[update]

```
{
        var test = "aaa-bbb-ccc";
        var data = test.split("-");

        data.forEach(function(entry) {
            if (entry != ""){
                $("#check_status_" + entry).html('!NEW!');
            }
        });
    }
```

nothing the same

Comment: There is an issue with your code, you can tell because even this site tells you something is wrong by the way things are highlighted.

Comment: You missed a quote near "url"...

Comment: ok but that's not the problem. thanks

Comment: I can't use entry like a variable.

Comment: What is the value of `entry`?

Comment: Are you sure that for any value might be coming back from you AJAX call in the '-' separated list, your DOM contains an element with the id 'check_status_FOO' where FOO is that value.  Also I would try putting a line at the beginning of the success callback like "console.log(data)" and then check the developer console to see that you are getting back what you expect.  Also are you sure you want dataType: 'json'.  If so then your file.php script needs to give it's output formatted as json so `"foo-bar-baz"` with the quotes.  If it's actually outputting `foo-bar-baz` then you want dataType: text

Comment: Can you please provide a more complete example?  It is hard to help if we have to guess at what your HTML looks like.

Comment: I have updated the script for another test. YOu can find it on the top. Anyway doesn't work. thanks

Comment: You just stated that the variable is a number, then why does your example use "aaa-bbb-ccc"?  Maybe you should try "1-2-3".

Comment: Also if I do just something like this var test = "test";
    $('#'+test).text('test'); 
this doesn't work. This is in a file .js. maybe could be it the problem ? thx

Comment: also this var test = "test"; $('#'+test).text('test'); 
doesn't work

Comment: Do you have an element with id="test"?  Just to be sure ;)

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine if you are [achieving something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/combizs/xw9MJ/)

```
data.forEach(function(entry) {
    if (entry) {
        $("#check_status_" + entry).html('text');
    }
});
```